# Setting up class for XML deserialization using Simple (XNA to Java porting)

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xna

I'm trying to port a class that I've used in XNA to Android. The class deals with reading an XML file.

I'm using Simple to do the serializing/deserializing however I'm not sure how to set up the classes and if I need getters/setters or not.

Here is the XNA code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace spritesheetanimation
{
    // Animation frame class
    public class Frame
    {
        // Frame Number
        [XmlAttribute("Num")]
        public int Num;

        // Sub Image X positon in the Sprite Sheet
        [XmlAttribute("X")]
        public int X;

        // Sub Image Y positon in the Sprite Sheet
        [XmlAttribute("Y")]
        public int Y;

        // Sub Image Width
        [XmlAttribute("Width")]
        public int Width;

        // Sub Image Height
        [XmlAttribute("Height")]
        public int Height;

        // The X offset of sub image
        [XmlAttribute("OffSetX")]
        public int OffsetX;

        // The Y offset fo sub image
        [XmlAttribute("OffsetY")]
        public int OffsetY;

        // The duration between two frames
        [XmlAttribute("Duration")]
        public float Duration;
    }

    // Animaiton class to hold the name and frames
    public class Animation
    {
        // Animation Name
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name;

        // Animation Frame Rate
        [XmlAttribute("FrameRate")]
        public int FrameRate;

        public bool Loop;

        public bool Pingpong;

        // The Frames array in an animation
        [XmlArray("Frames"), XmlArrayItem("Frame", typeof(Frame))]
        public Frame[] Frames;
    }

    // The Sprite Texture stores the Sprite Sheet path.fr
    public class SpriteTexture
    {
        // The Sprite Sheet texture file path
        [XmlAttribute("Path")]
        public string Path;
    }

    // Aniamtion Set contains the Sprite Texture and Animaitons.
    [XmlRoot("Animations")]
    public class AnimationSet
    {
        // The sprite texture object
        [XmlElement("Texture", typeof(SpriteTexture))]
        public SpriteTexture SpriteTexture;

        // The animation array in the Animation Set
        [XmlElement("Animation", typeof(Animation))]
        public Animation[] Animations;
    }

    // Sprite Animation Manager class
    public static class SpriteAnimationManager
    {
        public static int AnimationCount;

        // Read the Sprite Sheet Description information from the description xml file
        public static AnimationSet Read(string Filename)
        {
            AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet();

            // Create a XML reader for the sprite sheet animaiton description file
            using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(Filename))
            {
                // Create a XMLSerializer for the AnimationSet
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AnimationSet));

                // Deserialize the Animation Set from the XmlReader to the animation set object
                animationSet = (AnimationSet)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            // Count the animations to Animation Count
            AnimationCount = animationSet.Animations.Length;

            return animationSet;
        }
    }
}
```

To be compared with my code so far:

```
package com.example.sprites;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementArray;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;


public class SpriteAnimationManag implements
java.io.Serializable {
   // Animation frame class



   @Element(name = "Frame")
   public class Frame(int num, int x, int y, int width, int height,int offsetx,int offsety, int duration )
   {
      // Frame Number
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
      //[XmlAttribute("Num")]
      @Element(name = "Num")
      public int Num;

      // Sub Image X positon in the Sprite Sheet
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
      //[XmlAttribute("X")]
      @Element(name = "X")
      public int X;

      // Sub Image Y positon in the Sprite Sheet
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
      //[XmlAttribute("Y")]
      @Element(name = "Y")
      public int Y;

      // Sub Image Width
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
      //[XmlAttribute("Width")]
      @Element(name = "Width")
      public int Width;

      // Sub Image Height
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
      //[XmlAttribute("Height")]
      @Element(name = "Height")
      public int Height;

      // The X offset of sub image
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
      //[XmlAttribute("OffSetX")]
      @Element(name = "OffSetX")
      public int OffsetX;

      // The Y offset fo sub image
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
      //[XmlAttribute("OffsetY")]
      @Element(name = "OffSetY")
      public int OffsetY;

      // The duration between two frames
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
      //[XmlAttribute("Duration")]
      @Element(name = "Duration")
      public float Duration;
   }

   // Animaiton class to hold the name and frames
   public class Animation implements
   java.io.Serializable 
   {
      // Animation Name
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
      //[XmlAttribute("Name")]
      @Element(name = "Name")
      public String Name;

      // Animation Frame Rate
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
      //[XmlAttribute("FrameRate")]
      @Element(name = "FrameRate")
      public int FrameRate;


      public boolean Loop;

      public boolean Pingpong;

      // The Frames array in an animation
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
      //[XmlArray("Frames"), XmlArrayItem("Frame", typeof(Frame))]
      @ElementArray(name = "Frames") 
      public Frame[] Frames;
   }

   // The Sprite Texture stores the Sprite Sheet path.fr
   public class SpriteTexture implements
   java.io.Serializable 
   {
      // The Sprite Sheet texture file path
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
      //[XmlAttribute("Path")]
      @Element(name = "path")
      public String Path;
   }

   // Aniamtion Set contains the Sprite Texture and Animaitons.
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
   //[XmlRoot("Animations")]
   @Root
   public static class XNAAnimationSet implements
    java.io.Serializable
   {
      // The sprite texture object
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
      //[XmlElement("Texture", typeof(SpriteTexture))]
      @Element(name = "Texture")
      public SpriteTexture SpriteTexture;

      // The animation array in the Animation Set
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER TODO TASK: Java annotations will not correspond to .NET attributes:
      //[XmlElement("Animation", typeof(Animation))]
      @ElementArray(name = "Animation")
      public Animation[] Animations;
   }

   // Sprite Animation Manager class
   public final static class SpriteAnimationManager implements
    java.io.Serializable
   {
      private static final String XNAAnimationSet = null;//was static private static
      public static int AnimationCount;

      // Read the Sprite Sheet Description information from the description xml file
      public static XNAAnimationSet Read(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception
      {

          XNAAnimationSet animationSet = new XNAAnimationSet();


         // Create a XML reader for the sprite sheet animaiton description file
   //C# TO JAVA CONVERTER NOTE: The following 'using' block is replaced by its Java equivalent:
//       using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(Filename))
         //System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(Filename);
         //XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(Filename);//i added this 


            // Create a XMLSerializer for the AnimationSet
            //XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(AnimationSet);
                //i added below using simple//
             Serializer serializer = new Persister();
             //serializer.read(AnimationSet, Filename);
             try {
               animationSet = serializer.read(XNAAnimationSet.class, inputStream );
            } 
             catch (Exception e)
             {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ///////////////
            // Desesrialize the Animation Set from the XmlReader to the animation set object
         // animationSet = (AnimationSet)serializer1.Deserialize(reader);
            //serializer.write(AnimationSet, animationSet);
         //}
         //finally
         //{
            //reader.dispose(); //doesn'twork
      // }

         // Count the animations to Animation Count
         AnimationCount = animationSet.Animations.length;

         return animationSet;
      }
   }
}
```

And yes, I did put the code through a converter however I've changed it a lot (however yet to remove the auto-generated comments).

I just want to see how to set up one of the classes and I can probably do the rest myself, however I'm a novice programmer and I've spent the past 2 days searching and experimenting however there's several things I do not know.

Comment: It's generally better practice to post the relevant code in the question rather than just linking to external sites.

Comment: I tried however it wouldn't let me post since there was a problem getting all the code in a codebox format. It would randomly decide to exclude parts of the code and then not allow me to post

Comment: user1831330: Sounds like you have never written in markdown before. Take a look at markdown code syntax when you write everything.

Comment: I have an alias to help with this: alias markdown-prepare="sed 's/\(.*\)/    \1/'"

Answer (score 0):

The way that simple-xml works is that you Annotate a class with tags and then you call a function to actually serialize the data. Take a look at this example from my [blog post on the topic](http://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/):

```
// Create the Dummy Level with Apples and Oranges
Log.i(TAG, "Create level");
Level level = new Level();
Orange orange;
level.gameObjects.add(new Apple(1, 10));
orange = new Orange(2);
orange.containedJuice = 20;
level.gameObjects.add(orange);
orange = new Orange(3);
orange.containedJuice = 100;
level.gameObjects.add(orange);
level.gameObjects.add(new Apple(4, 0));

// Now write the level out to a file
Log.i(TAG, "Write Level to file.");
Serializer serial = new Persister();
File sdcardFile = new File("/sdcard/levelout.xml");

try {
   serial.write(level, sdcardFile);
} catch (Exception e) {
   // There is the possibility of error for a number of reasons. Handle this appropriately in your code
   e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.i(TAG, "XML Written to File: " + sdcardFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Now really there are only three steps here:

1. Create the 'Level' object.
2. Create a 'Serializer' object and specify where you want to write the xml.
3. Actually write the XML using the 'serial.write' function

To perform a read you still need a 'Level' class that is annotated but you call the 'read' function on the 'Serializer' class instead and it constructs a class for you. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Actually I did look at your post earlier.

However I can't figure out how to annotate the classes, which is my trouble. For example I tried having a public class Frame (int a, int b) {} but it wants me to declare it void, which leads to further problems. 

You can see the XNA code to see what I am trying to do (it's actually very clean and not very XNA specific)

Comment: If you don't know how to annotate the classes then that is what the Simple XML tutorial is for: http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php

Comment: Aha I was reading it but not getting it apparently. Just one last question in XNA there's markup for an element "Typeof", is this the equivalent of "attribute"?

Comment: Is that the type of class that the element will be? In the event of generic types? Because SimpleXML has something like that too but I cannot remember what it is called off the top of my head.

Comment: That's why I added my C# code which is very clean and easy to read and WORKS, so you can see what I'm trying to do. 

So yes I guess that's the type of class the element will be. Is this even necessary? When I take it out of my C# code it works regardless.

Comment: No it should not be required in the general case. And for your example I think not.